# How to get inputted text from text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying to establish a connection with SignalR in an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application. What I need to do is let a user write in a text area and upon clicking I am trying to send the message written by the user to all clients on the same page.

I am stuck in a very simple step. To read what the user writes in the textarea I am using the following code:

```
var msg = $('#editor').text();
alert(msg);
```

I am using the alert box for testing purposes. The problem is that the alert box is being shown empty i.e. the message is not being read properly. editor is the id of my text area in the html file.

This is all the JavaScript file:

```
$(function ()
    {
        var edit = $.connection.editorHub;

        edit.client.broadcastMessage = function (message) {

            var msg = $('#editor').text();
            alert(msg);

            // Add the message to the page. 
            $('#editor').append(msg);
        };

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#button').click(function () {
               // call the send method in EditorHub
                chat.server.send($('#editor').val());
            });
        });
    });
```

This is the HTML file:

```
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "- Editor";
   ViewBag.ContentStyle = "/Content/CSS/editor.css";
}

 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" ></script>
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js"></script>
 <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/tinyMCE/tiny_mce.js" ></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/EditorHandler.js"></script>

 <button id="button">Click me</button>

 <form>  
       <textarea id="editor" name="content" cols="100" rows="30">
   </textarea>
 </form>
```

It is loaded through ajax therefore this is the content.. The remainder is in a Master file

Comment: what is `#editor` and why would have a function called `text()`?  (We need to see the HTML too)

Comment: Html File submitted.. #editor is the textarea as seen above

Comment: Next time please specify when you're using something like tinymce, which modifies the text area.

Comment: will be more careful next time! Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to get the value from the textarea, not the text() :

```
$('#editor').val();
```

Or to get the content from TinyMCE:

```
var msg = tinyMCE.get('#editor').getContent()
```

or

```
var msg = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

Comment: @adeneo most likely tinyMCE is hiding the editor and replacing it with it's own, you'll need to tell tinyMCE to push the content from the tinyMCE editor to the hidden textarea.

Comment: hmmm interesting point @KevinB that may be the case! Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @KevinB - If that's the case, something like `tinyMCE.get('#editor').getContent()` would get the text inputted into TinyMCE!

Comment: tried the statement above and now the alert box is not showing though there are no errors!

Comment: Then open the console (F12) and look for errors. Do a search for TinyMCE and read the documentation on that, there are several methods built in to get the typed in text, but I can't remember them all now.

Comment: I found the way :) var msg = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent(); there was a method in tinyMCE to get the content :) Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @Bernice - Sure, added that to the answer as well, but if that works, it's strange that the get() method does'nt. But anyway, just happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

I note a strange difference between two parts of your code:

Here we use `val()`

```
 chat.server.send($('#editor').val());
```

Here we use `text()`

```
 var msg = $('#editor').text();
```

I'm guessing you want these to use the same function.  Probably val() but can't know for sure with the code you posted.

Comment: You have a point there. However when I changed them both to val() I got the same result. For some reason msg is remaining null!